# Start ignite with spring boot in service on request

Tags: java, spring-boot, ignite

Spring boot requires to create a bean instance. Due to which the pods are started as I run the application

```
 @Bean
    Ignite ignite(IgniteConfiguration igniteConfiguration) {
        Ignition.start(igniteConfiguration)
    }
```

Is there any way that I can configure and start it in spring boot service on receiving a request?

Answer (score 1):

You can add @Lazy annotation for bean declaration and also combine @Lazy with @Autowired annotation in your service.

More information here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Lazy.html

Answer (score 1):

This is not recommended, because Ignite startup may be a lengthy process, and you probably don't want to wait for it upon getting a request (only to learn that startup failed, for example) and certainly not start it per request.

Also, consider using IgniteSpringBean instead of raw Ignite.